# Using ExecutorService with a multithreaded version of Merge Sort

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

I am working on a homework problem where I have to create a Multithreaded version of Merge Sort.   I was able to implement it, but I am not able to stop the creation of threads.   I looked into using an ExecutorService to limit the creation of threads but I cannot figure out how to implement it within my current code.

Here is my current Multithreaded Merge Sort.  We are required to implement a specific strategy pattern so that is where my `sort()` method comes from.

```
@Override
public int[] sort(int[] list) {
    int array_size = list.length;
    list = msort(list, 0, array_size-1);
    return list;
}

int[] msort(int numbers[], int left, int right) {
    final int mid;
    final int leftRef = left;
    final int rightRef = right;
    final int array[] = numbers;
    if (left<right) {
        mid = (right + left) / 2;
        //new thread
        Runnable r1 = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                msort(array, leftRef, mid);     
            }
        };
        Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
        t1.start();

        //new thread
        Runnable r2 = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                msort(array, mid+1, rightRef);
            }
        };
        Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
        t2.start();
        //join threads back together
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        merge(numbers, leftRef, mid, mid+1, rightRef);
    }
    return numbers;
}

void merge(int numbers[], int startA, int endA, int startB, int endB) {
    int finalStart = startA;
    int finalEnd = endB;
    int indexC = 0;
    int[] listC = new int[numbers.length];

    while(startA <= endA && startB <= endB){
        if(numbers[startA] < numbers[startB]){
            listC[indexC] = numbers[startA];
            startA = startA+1;
        }
        else{
            listC[indexC] = numbers[startB];
            startB = startB +1;
        }
        indexC++;
    }

    if(startA <= endA){
        for(int i = startA; i < endA; i++){
            listC[indexC]= numbers[i];
            indexC++;
        }
    }

    indexC = 0;
    for(int i = finalStart; i <= finalEnd; i++){
        numbers[i]=listC[indexC];
        indexC++;
    }
}
```

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Comment: Just set some kind of "count" in your msort(): "ExecutorService()" is overkill.  IMHO...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the way I see it, if you limit the number of threads with your current design, the code will never finish. You need the results from the 'bottom-level' threads so that `join()` will return on the next 'layer'.

Comment: I suggest you look for articles on ForkJoinTask, which is intended for just this sort of thing - e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: You only want to create a new thread when you have a very large amount of data to sort e.g. 10+K . Creating a thread for much less than this likely to have more overhead than benefit.  You only need to create one thread not two as you already have one running thread. BTW you are likely to want to limit the number of threads to the number of CPUs you have.

Comment: Your merge method looks pretty wrong&wasteful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @mcdowella's comment, I also think that the fork/join framework is your best bet if you want to limit the number of threads that run in parallel.

I know that this won't give you any help on your homework, because you are probably not allowed to use the fork/join framework in Java7. However it is about to learn something, isn't it?;)

As I commented, I think your merge method is wrong. I can't pinpoint the failure, but I have rewritten it. I strongly suggest you to write a testcase with all the edge cases that can happen during that merge method and if you verified it works, plant it back to your multithreaded code.

@lbalazscs also gave you the hint that the fork/join sort is mentioned in the javadocs, however I had nothing else to do- so I will show you the solution if you'd implemented it with Java7.

```
public class MultithreadedMergeSort extends RecursiveAction {

  private final int[] array;
  private final int begin;
  private final int end;

  public MultithreadedMergeSort(int[] array, int begin, int end) {
    this.array = array;
    this.begin = begin;
    this.end = end;
  }

  @Override
  protected void compute() {
    if (end - begin < 2) {
      // swap if we only have two elements
      if (array[begin] > array[end]) {
        int tmp = array[end];
        array[end] = array[begin];
        array[begin] = tmp;
      }
    } else {
      // overflow safe method to calculate the mid
      int mid = (begin + end) >>> 1;
      // invoke recursive sorting action
      invokeAll(new MultithreadedMergeSort(array, begin, mid),
          new MultithreadedMergeSort(array, mid + 1, end));
      // merge both sides
      merge(array, begin, mid, end);
    }
  }

  void merge(int[] numbers, int startA, int startB, int endB) {
    int[] toReturn = new int[endB - startA + 1];
    int i = 0, k = startA, j = startB + 1;
    while (i < toReturn.length) {
      if (numbers[k] < numbers[j]) {
        toReturn[i] = numbers[k];
        k++;
      } else {
        toReturn[i] = numbers[j];
        j++;
      }
      i++;
      // if we hit the limit of an array, copy the rest
      if (j > endB) {
        System.arraycopy(numbers, k, toReturn, i, startB - k + 1);
        break;
      }
      if (k > startB) {
        System.arraycopy(numbers, j, toReturn, i, endB - j + 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    System.arraycopy(toReturn, 0, numbers, startA, toReturn.length);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] toSort = { 55, 1, 12, 2, 25, 55, 56, 77 };
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    pool.invoke(new MultithreadedMergeSort(toSort, 0, toSort.length - 1));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toSort));

  }
```

Note that the construction of your threadpool limits the number of active parallel threads to the number of cores of your processor.

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
```

According to it's javadoc:

> Creates a ForkJoinPool with parallelism equal to
>   java.lang.Runtime.availableProcessors, using the default thread
>   factory, no UncaughtExceptionHandler, and non-async LIFO processing
>   mode.

Also notice how my merge method differs from yours, because I think that is your main problem. At least your sorting works if I replace your merge method with mine.

Comment: Thank for providing the Java7 Multithreaded merge sort, it sorts to much faster than mine, its incredible.  I was able to use your merge method to make corrections to mine.

Answer (score 1):

As mcdowella pointed out, the Fork/Join framework in Java 7 is exactly for tasks that can be broken into smaller pieces recursively.

Actually, the Javadoc for [RecursiveAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html) has a merge sort as the first example :)

Also note that [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) is an ExecutorService.